# where can I find ACEGI security documents and examples?

Tags: spring-security

I have an old project that uses the now gone acegi framework and needs to do some work on it. I could not find any useful info on the internet. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this java world article  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2007/jw-10-acegi2.html.  You can also do a search from java world and come up with some good results for acegi there.